# How to procedurally compose shaders?

Tags: opengl, c++, shaders, opengl-es3

I read several times that shaders can be composed by the engine on the fly, depending on graphical settings.
How is this generally done?

Comment: The answer to this question seems really trivial: You generate the shader sourcecode through string concatenation, and then you call `glShaderSource` and `glCompileShader`. But maybe the problem you have is actually more in the details? Can you elaborate on what problem you specifically face in your current project regarding shader generation?

Comment: In the main body of your question you ask how shaders are composed on the fly. In your title you ask how to procedurally compose shaders. Which one is it? Are you trying to write your first shader? Or are you trying to randomise how shaders look like the same way a randomised roguelike dungeon is generated ?

Comment: I thought about string concatenation, but wondered about established practices to make the engine write shaders depenting of settings. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way that shaders are adapted depending on settings is through compiler directives like define macros and conditional compilation.

You can see a lot of examples of this if you look through the shader code of a free-to-use game engine like Unity (not specifically written in OpenGL-style glsl, though they use transpilers to output their shader code to OpenGL-compatible versions):

```
output.screenUV = output.positionCS.xyw;
#if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
output.screenUV.xy = output.screenUV.xy * float2(0.5, -0.5) + 0.5 * output.screenUV.z;
#else
output.screenUV.xy = output.screenUV.xy * 0.5 + 0.5 * output.screenUV.z;
#endif
```

This lets the shader adapt to different graphics APIs' conventions on where the (0, 0) point of a texture is: top-left for DirectX-like APIs, and bottom-left for OpenGL-like.

Here `UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP` is a macro that gets replaced by a constant during compilation. When invoking the shader compiler, the engine will include a shader source file with the needed constants for the platform/graphics API it's targeting. For instance, in `D3D11.hlsl` there's a line saying:

```
#define UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP 1
```

So when the compiler gets to `#if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP`, that compiles to `#if 1` (ie. "yes") and the first version of the code gets compiled into the resulting shader, and the second version gets skipped over by the compiler.

If we were compiling this for OpenGL, we'd instead have defined this macro to be zero, and the first version of the code would be skipped over, compiling the second version into the resulting shader.

These macros can also define whole blocks of code - functions that do different things depending on needs, variable declarations that change their format or syntax to match what the platform wants, etc.

A deep material and lighting system will use these types of compiler switches for all sorts of things, including:

- Whether a feature is supported on a given graphics card. If not, replace the code that uses the feature with code that emulates the feature, or uses a graceful fallback instead.
- Whether this material is being lit by a spot- or point light (rays diverge) or a directional light (rays parallel) - this would swap out the math that calculates the lighting vector and attenuation factors, while leaving the code that *uses* these values to actually compute the colour common to both paths.
- Whether the material uses a particular feature, like detail maps. If not, the code that applies them can be compiled out of its shader entirely, rather than leaving a runtime branch that will never be taken.
- Whether the player has enabled an optional feature, like parallax occlusion mapping. If so, the code to do it is included. If not, it's stripped out or replaced with a cheaper fallback.

...etc.

This can result in a lot of code handling all these different cases, so in a large engine this will usually be parcelled off into several separate shader files that individual material shaders simply "include", rather than copy-pasting all this logic into every shader and creating a maintenance nightmare.

On modern graphics APIs, to save load times, a lot of this compilation is done in advance at edit/build time, stamping out the permutations of the shaders the engine will need for the given game content in a more efficient "intermediate representation" that can be digested by the graphics driver faster than parsing files upon files of human-readable code.

It's also possible to compile shaders from raw text, allowing you to just concatenate together a string with whatever code you want it to run. This is commonly how it's done in JavaScript for WebGL apps since we don't have a binary build in the same way as a native app. But for non-web applications, this is something you'd usually do only if you need extremely open-ended shader editing at runtime, like if you were making a shader graph material editor for users to create their own bespoke material effects. If you just want to apply some small, fixed set of settings tweaks, conditional compilation handles that in a more structured way, with fewer complications like needing to come up with non-colliding variable names in each block of code that's concatenated-on.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation DMGregory, you're very helpful as always :)

Answer (score -1):

Different shaders are compiled/loaded depending on the settings selected. This is generally why games ask you to restart the game, so the correct shader can be loaded when the game boots and why you can't change some settings while the game is running, i.e. only from the main menu.

Comment: This seems to answer "why" do games compose shaders on the fly depending on settings, but not the "how".

Comment: I have to admit that my experience with programming pure OpenGL is rather limited, but I don't see why it should be impossible to recompile and apply shader changes while the game is running. Changes which require to restart the game completley are usually the case because the programmers were too lazy to implement hot-reloading of those changes. Not because it's *actually* technically imposisble.

Comment: Incorrect. Reloading shaders by themselves does not require game restart, or even render context reinit. @Philipp you are right - game restart could be needed in case of Windows being incapable of updating RC (render context). Even then, it's quite simple to pre-plan to recreate the canvaas and get new RC without restart.

Comment: I'd imagine the restart after changing graphics settings in many games has more to do with memory allocation. If the app allocates all its memory once at start-up and then just parcels out from there, changing things like the texture budget could force it to move stuff around. There the developers probably decided it was easier/less bug-prone to simply restart, and let the existing allocate-on-start-up code do the right thing in one place, rather than introduce more cooks into the kitchen.

Comment: @Casey: yes it's the type of flexibility I'm trying to implement! Thanks for your answer.